# how can i use advanced renamer to add modified date to the maximum lenght of the files names?

Tags: windows-10, batch, mp3, filenames, batch-rename

here is the command that describes what i want to do

```
<Name><max space possible><Year Modified><Month Modified><Day Modified>
```

so the Modified date won't show up unless i extended the  column of file names....
what prevented me from doing this ... that is my files doesn't have the same name length .......so is there any possible way to do this ?

what i have tried
[image: what i have tried]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using java script

```
var maxLength = 222;
var name = item.name;
var date = app.parseTags("<Year Modified><Month Modified><Day Modified>");
var numSpaces = maxLength - name.length - date.length;
var spaces = "";
for (i = 0; i < numSpaces; i++) spaces += " ";
return name + spaces + date;
```

credits [David Lee from advanced Renamer forms](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/users_show?user_id=2502)